# Computing and generating plot for the Probability of Exceedance in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, probability

I am trying to compute `probability of exceedance` in R. Here is the [link](https://sciencing.com/calculate-exceedance-probability-5365868.html) that has detail and formula for computing exceedance probability. I tried to replicate the procedure with the following sample code, however,  I am no way near the attached example plotting. Once, i figured out how to do this- i would then like to apply the procedure on a `data.frame` that has multiple `variables`.

```
library(tidyverse)

A = sample(0:5000, 2500)
A = A[order(A, decreasing = TRUE)]
Rank = 1:2500

DF = data.frame(cbind(A,Rank))
DF$Prob =  100*(DF$Rank/(length(DF$Prob+1)))

ggplot(data = DF, aes(x=Prob, y=A))+
  geom_line() + scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10")
```

Here is a sample of the plot that i would like to produce
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula to compute `Prob`is not well implemented in the question. it is adding 1 to `DF$Prob` and then taking its `length` when it should add 1 *to* the `length`.

```
DF <- data.frame(A, Rank)
DF$Prob <-  DF$Rank/(length(DF$Rank) + 1)

ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Prob, y = A)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.20),
                     labels = percent) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10")
```

[image]

**Data creation code.**

I have changed the data set example.
The code below is reproducible, since `set.seed` is used and the `sample` has decreasing probabilities.

```
set.seed(1234)
A <- sample(0:5000, 2500, prob = exp(seq(10, 0, length.out = 5001)))
A <- A[order(A, decreasing = TRUE)]
Rank <- 1:2500
```

Comment: Thanks. What is `prob = exp(seq(10, 0, length.out = 5001))` doing? is it is possible to implement the procedure to a data.frame? such as for `DF = data.frame(A = runif(8000, 5,800), B = runif(8000, 0, 1000), C = runif(8000, 2,700), D = runif(8000, 1,600))` ? there should be some packages that would compute exceedance probability automatically??

Comment: @Hydro The `prob = exp(...)` code is just meant as a way to have more draws from the lower limit of `0:5000`. It has very little to do with the problem itself, it is used to create a *fake* data set, not more.

Comment: Thanks- i found this package that would do the `fdc (flow duration curve)` also known as `exceedance probability` automatically. I am going to put it is a separate question as i have few questions there- hope someone has answers to them.

Comment: See chapter 10 of this Virginia Tech Hydroinformatics book by JP Gannon - https://vt-hydroinformatics.github.io/fdcs.html